# Why does my Nikon D90 make a strange sound during built-in sensor cleaning, when my friend's D90 doesn't?

Tags: nikon, sensor, nikon-d90, cleaning, troubleshooting

I noticed a quiet sound (like squeaking) when using the built-in sensor cleaning of my Nikon D90. In some forums I read about many people having this behavior with the Nikon D700 and some Canon cameras. It is often called a side effect of the ultra-sonic cleaning, but a friend of mine also got the D90 and he does not have this sound.

Does any one know anything about this?

Comment: Are you sure that the second D90 doesn't make the sound, are you positive its not just much softer than yours?

Comment: I am pretty sure about this, if there is a sound on the second one, it must be very much more silent.

Comment: Custom menu e4 "sensor cleaning volume" ?  :) jk

Comment: It's about to *explode!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Nikon's website:

*Sensor cleaning takes approximately 3 seconds to complete. During this time a high pitched noise may be heard. This nearly inaudible squeal is just slightly louder with the D300 than the D700, and this may be due to the different sensors used in these cameras. The D90 noise is slight as well, but is audible is you listen closely enough.*

http://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers//detail/a_id/16067

My D90 makes a very faint "sqeak" and slight vibration. I can hear and feel this only if I hold the camera body against my ear (or very near my ear in a quiet room).

I wouldn't be surprised to find that different camera bodies make different sounds, since those vibrations would be felt throughout the camera body and anything, say a memory card, could vibrate and contribute to the noise.  There are thousands of parts in there that could be vibrating.  At least you can hear yours, and know it's working

Comment: I can't feel any vibrations on my D90, but the sound is louder than usual. You can hear it, even if you are 1/2 meter away. I'm just a bit worried about the camera being damaged due shipping. The camera is full functional, thus I assume this sound is a usual behavior and its loudness depends on every single camera.